# resizing iframe with jquery revisited

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have a wordpress page which includes an iframe. This iframe contains 3 iframes stacked one below the other and they increase in height as data is added to a database. I want them to resize automatically and have researched extensively to find a solution. All the pages are on my own server. I have got this working in Chrome, Opera, and Maxthon but some of my members insist on using Firefox & the script does not work on FF.

This is an example of one of the iframes to be resized:

```
<iframe src="a page on my domain" width="100%" height="100%" id="iframe1" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" onLoad="autoResize('iframe1');"></iframe>
```

Here is my code:

```
<script>
    function autoResize(id){
        var newheight;
        var newwidth;
            if(document.getElementById){
            newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollHeight;
            newwidth=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollWidth;
            }
        document.getElementById(id).height= (newheight) + "px";
        document.getElementById(id).width= (newwidth) + "px";
    }
</script>
```

If only it would work in Firefox I would be happy :)

Comment: remove the space from document .body - firefox is less forgiving on javascript - try that first (shouldn't be problem but you never know!)

Comment: Agreed with above. Run it with your dev console open (F12) and check the output for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Remove height="100%"

$(function () 
    {
        $('iframe').height($('iframe').contents().height()); 
    });

Comment: Don't put it in the inside autoResize()